# How to restrict an integer to a range in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an instance variable `@limit` which must be greater than 0 and no greater than 20. I currently have code like this:

```
@limit = (params[:limit] || 10).to_i
@limit = 20 if @limit > 20
@limit = 0 if @limit < 0
```

This looks ugly. Is there a better way to restrict an integer to a range of values?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Comparable#clamp` is [available in Ruby 2.4](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10594).

```
3.clamp(10, 20)
=> 10

27.clamp(10, 20)
=> 20

15.clamp(10, 20)
=> 15
```

Answer (score 19):

How about using [`Enumerable#min`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min), [`Enumerable#max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max)?

For example, to limit the value in range `0..10`:

```
x = 100
[[10, x].min, 0].max
# => 10

x = -2
[[10, x].min, 0].max
# => 0

x = 5
[[10, x].min, 0].max
# => 5
```

---

Alternative, Using [`Enumerable#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort):

```
x = 100
[x, 0, 10].sort[1]
# => 10

x = -2
[x, 0, 10].sort[1]
# => 0

x = 5
[x, 0, 10].sort[1]
# => 5
```

Comment: The sort solution is excellent too, and easier to read I think.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a quick benchmark to show which method we should use. Because someone will inevitably say "Use `sort_by` because it's faster than `sort`", I added it. `sort_by` is only faster than `sort` when dealing with complex objects. Basic objects, like integers and strings should be handled by `sort`.

```
require 'fruity'

class Numeric
  def clamp(min, max)
    self < min ? min : self > max ? max : self
  end
end

compare do
  min_max { [[10, 100].min, 0].max }
  sort { [100, 0, 10].sort[1] }
  sort_by { [100, 0, 10].sort_by{ |v| v }[1] }
  clamp_test { 10.clamp(0, 100) }
  original {
    limit = 10
    limit = 100 if limit > 100
    limit = 0 if limit < 0
    limit
  }
end
```

With the results being:

```
Running each test 65536 times. Test will take about 8 seconds.
original is faster than clamp_test by 2x ± 1.0
clamp_test is faster than sort by 6x ± 1.0
sort is faster than min_max by 2x ± 0.1
min_max is faster than sort_by by 2x ± 0.1
```

Sometimes ugly is better.

Comment: Does it really seem like this is going to be a performance bottleneck?

Comment: It depends on the code that's using it. Call this sort of algorithm a couple hundred thousand times and it adds up. Knowing the fastest way to go is always a good idea, then we can balance speed and readability and code style.

Comment: "Sometimes ugly is better"
I liked it! :)

Comment: `Comparable#clamp` is coming to Ruby 2.4 http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/12/13/ruby-2-4-adds-comparable-clamp-method.html?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email

Answer (score 6):

If you feel like monkey patching a method, you might do something like this:

```
class Numeric
  def clamp(min, max)
    self < min ? min : self > max ? max : self
  end
end

# usage
@limit = (params[:limit] || 10).clamp(0, 20)
```

Comment: Clamp is a great method name for it.

Comment: I searched for `constrain` and was surprised not to find it built-in

Comment: `Comparable#clamp` is coming to Ruby 2.4 http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/12/13/ruby-2-4-adds-comparable-clamp-method.html?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, here's a monkey-patch for the "ugly and better" solution that wins the Tin Man's benchmark elsewhere on this page. (It should be a tiny bit faster by returning immediately if the boundary's exceeded.)

```
class Numeric
  def clamp(min, max)
    return min if self < min
    return max if self > max
    self
  end
end
```

Answer (score -3):

`(1..19).cover? @limit`

See [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) for details.

Comment: Useful method, but doesn't solve the problem of locking the integer within a range.